# Can i convert xlsb file to xlsx using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, machine-learning, analytics

I was trying to convert `xlsb` file to `xlsx` using Python but I am not able to figure out my problem in my all unsuccessful attempts.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


source='C:\\Users\\JS Developer\\sample.xlsb'
dest= 'C:\\Users\\JS Developer\\Desktop\\New folder'
os.chdir(source)

for file in glob.glob("*.xlb"):
  df.to_csv(dest+file+'.csv', index=False)
  os.remove(file)

for file in glob.glob("*.xlsb"):
       df = pd.read_excel(file)
       df.to_csv(dest+file+'.csv', index=False)
       os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you read the excel and stored it in pandas dataframe save it as

```
df.to_excel(r'Path\name.xlsx')
```

Try:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.xlsb"):
   df = pd.read_excel(file)
   df.to_excel(dest+file+'.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
   os.remove(file)
```